# Inconsistency With Date Conversion in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a weird issue with the conversion of Dates from `Varchar` to `Date` that I'm hoping someone can explain to me why it's happening.

Right now I have a handful of temp tables that I use a `Bulk Insert` to insert CSV files into. These Temp tables are taking everything in as a `Varchar()`, and from there I insert the data into their final tables. Now for most of the data, I've used the `Cast()` function to convert fields from `varchar()` to whatever their final type needs to be, but on a few of the date fields, I simple changed the final table to a `Date` type, and didn't bother with a `cast()` function. Oddly enough, simply setting the final table to a `Date` type, things converted fine, but when trying to do this with one of the other tables, I'm getting a Conversion Failed Error.

Are there any situations where dates will convert without needing a `convert()` or `Cast()` function? I'm not doing anything crazy with these insert queries, just simply inserting data from one table to the next. Why would changing the final table field type be enough to convert the date in one situation, but not enough in the other? Again, we're talking about simple `Insert` statements here.

Comment: A date in the format `'YYYYMMDD'` should convert fine, even without a `cast()`.

Comment: All these dates are in the format of MMDDYYYY

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 then it's in an ambiguous format, you need to specify it explicitely with `CONVERT`

Comment: @Lamak While I don't disagree with your statement, I'm confused as to why it would still convert the date in one situation but not the other.

Comment: because it's performing an implicit cast anyway, and it's assuming whatever format it fits, so it may work for some data and not for other

Comment: 12312015 is not as ambiguous as 01022015. Is it converting the dates where the day of the month is 13 or higher?